# Stereo Width in Oktava M/S recordings

Tags: field-recording, ambience, mid-side, ms, oktava

I wanted to experiment with M/S as I had not tried it before so set up a cheap rig using a couple of Oktavas with the figure of 8 adapter.

I've done a few recordings outside my window and mastered them to LCR as per the Tim Neilson M/S article on Designing Sound.

I wondered if I could get some feedback on the recording as to my ears the stereo does not sound wide at all and I wondered if this is what M/S recordings usually sound like. Obviously I've tried balancing the Mid to the side increase the width but I'm just not sure if I have the mics set up properly.

I wondered whether I had not achieved a proper stereo image due to the placement of the mid mic in relation to the side. Any advice and feedback appreciated.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/686976/AMB%20Hackney%20Skyline%2C%20Morning%2C%20Gulls%2C%20Construction%20LCR.wav

Cheers

Comment: Hi can you add a picture from your setup? This will make it easier to judge any misalignment. Oh and you have the correct routing or a matrix plugin inserted, right?

Comment: Hi, yeah I have decoded the L and R channels with a matrix plugin, then used the raw mid for the center channel. Here's a pic https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/686976/unnamed.jpg

Comment: Links broken, post useless. Downvoted (recorded since I don't have enough rep currently).

Answer (score 2):

It's stereo alright, but not much more. I love the Oktava 012 for many things (which I assume you are using as you mentioned the Figure Of 8-adapter), it's one of my go-to mics for several types of ambiances for one, especially when building perspective against maybe a MKH40 or a DPA 4012. But that adapter isn't very good, regretfully. For a microphone to really work with M/S, the positive and negative parts ***>must<*** be perfectly placed with little to absolutely no space in between, preferably as a single membrane. The 012 adapter, fully mounted, have nearly 2cm as I recall. It will not work, and the effect is what you got there - only one dominant channel and that's it.

Comment: These were recorded with the Oktava m/s rig and sound pretty good to me http://rabbitearsaudio.com/product/la-underground/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this setup before, am only experienced with the sennheiser mkh30. But it seems like the side mic has   very widely spaced capsules. That could explain some issues, but i'm not sure to be honest. What type of mid mic is that?

Regardless of the microphone, why did want/need to create an LCR file? It sounds stereophonic, but M/S is theoretically just 2 signals that make a stereo image.

Did you read the comments below the article? There's a good explanation why it won't work as a real LCR recording (3 vs 2 capsules).

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the hypercardioid capsule for the mid as the two cardioid capsules are used to make the figure of 8. Also tried with an omni cap which unsurpringly resulted in even less stereo image.

Comment: Regarding the LCR, having read this http://designingsound.org/2011/08/tim-nielsen-special-ms-recording/ I was just interested to see if it worked well and whether it would be worth mastering in LCR as I often find LCR roomtones useful for film sound editing.

Comment: Thanks, I did read the comments so just wanted to see for myself. While it may not create a real 3 channel file I was interested in whether it was still usable.

Comment: Well you did create a 3 channel file :) It's useable, but it's not the way the industry standard works.. Read a bit about phase issues in dolby setups and M/S recordings, some mixers hate M/S.

Comment: This is quite interesting: http://duc.avid.com/archive/index.php/t-267002.html particularly Tim Nielson's response near the bottom.

Comment: Well to be honest, Tim is referring to AB as XY and vice versa.. which is quite odd. However phase issues will mostly occur with too loud Side channels indeed, but using a non cardiod mic will also result in issues (because of the math behind MS). check out the overview of ms fields here on page 5 etc. : http://www.wesdooley.com/pdf/technique.pdf

Comment: Thanks, that was really useful. It would be great if any dubbing mixers working in 5.1 could chime in and discuss any phase problems m/s might incur and how to avoid them?

Comment: Hi mattw, perhaps it's better to ask that as a seperate question. It will get more attention and we keep things separated. This way we also keep the amount of comments in check.

Answer (score 0):

I listen to it via a measured stereo Setup in the studio, but there´s a lot going on in the right speaker. nearly nothing in the left. Is this wanted ?

Comment: Are you downmixing the LCR to stereo? Or just listening to the first 2 channels?